# Implement z-index to the particular div element

Tags: html, css, z-index

hi all i wanted to put the z-index to ensure that the "Event today" will be behind the element(collapse).
Here is my code below....

```
    <div id="infobox" class="collapse"  >
                <table id="attacks" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"  >
                    <thead style="z-index:10">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Attacker</th>
                            <th>Target</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Attacker</th>
                            <th>Target</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>

<div class="toolbar-left2 noselect" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">Events Today: <font></font></td>
                <td id="totalattack" style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">0      </td>
                <td align="right"id="todaytime" style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">Current Time</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

My question is how to ensure that the clock element is behind the element which contains the class collapse...Please help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `z-index: -10` **does indeed** make your element appear behind other elements.

Only content that is 'positioned', such as with **[`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)**, **[`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)** or **[`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Relative_positioning)** will respect `z-index`. Note that the default `position: static` does **not** obey `z-index`.

Also, keep in mind that the default `z-index` is `0`.  Although your element will **appear** to be on top of elements such as `<body>` and `<html>`, it will actually be **behind** them.

Here's a working example, showcasing that your element gets hidden behind a red square:

```css
#sample {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar-left2 noselect" style="z-index:-10">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">Events Today:
        <font></font>
      </td>
      <td id="totalattack" style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">0 </td>
      <td align="right" id="todaytime" style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">Current Time</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="sample"></div>
```

In your example, you'll need to add a `position` to both `.collapse` and `.noselect`, and make sure to give `.collapse` a higher `z-index` than `.noselect`. In the following example, I've also changed the text to red to help illustrate this:

```css
.collapse {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: red;
}

.noselect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="infobox" class="collapse">
  <table id="attacks" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead style="z-index:10">
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Attacker</th>
        <th>Target</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Attacker</th>
        <th>Target</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="toolbar-left2 noselect">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">Events Today:
        <font></font>
      </td>
      <td id="totalattack" style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">0 </td>
      <td align="right" id="todaytime" style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">Current Time</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi all, I have updated my code. Can you please help me again

Comment: I wanted to ensure the div element which contains the clock with timing and event today to be behind the div element which display(collapse bootstrap)

Comment: @AbdullahShaik -- I've updated my answer to cover your updated question.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah -- I've updated my answer to help clarify the `z-index` relation to `<body>` and `<html>`, along with a note on `position: static`.

Answer (score 0):

> An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

By default, the `z-index` of `html` and `body` is `0`.  When only setting `z-index` of an element to a negative number, it's going to be behind even `html` and `body`.

If you have a background set on `html` and/or `body` that would cover your element with a negative `z-index`, then you can remove the background(s) to verify that the element is, in fact, behind `html` and `body`.

Note: The `z-index` property has no effect on statically positioned elements.